# Howto mount sd card at startup - Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, startup, automount, sd-card

I need to run backups to my sdcard on a regular basis. But unfortunately xubuntu 14.04 doesn't mount my sdcard at startup. Can you guys point me to the right direction on howto make xubuntu automount the sdcard everytime at startup to the same directory?

Cheers

Comment: `man fstab` would be a good starting point...

Comment: thanx Alex! I also found out if one wants to use the internal udisk2 mounting option provided by xubuntu 14.04. In my case the sd card reader show up as /dev/mmcblk0p1, so with command `udisksctl mount -b /dev/mmcblk0p1` in a bash script that will be run at startup solves my problem.

Comment: @Chiggiddi This question seems to have been solved in last comment. That should be able to [self-answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) i.e. post and accept your own answer.